# Mongoose difficult design choice

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So, I have this big schema and a dilemma.

```
var PortfolioSchema = new Schema({
    bonds              :  {
        percentage          :  Number,
        USA                 :  {
            percentage           :  Number,
            treasury             :  {
                percentage            :  Number,
                securities            :  [ { 
                    percentage             :  Number,
                    absolutePercentage     :  Number,
                    info                   :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'security' }
                } ]
            },
            municipal            :  {
                percentage            :  Number,
                securities            :  [ { 
                    percentage             :  Number,
                    absolutePercentage     :  Number,
                    info                   :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'security' }
                } ]
            },
            corporate            :  {
                percentage            :  Number,
                securities            :  [ { 
                    percentage             :  Number,
                    absolutePercentage     :  Number,
                    info                   :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'security' }
                } ]
            }
        },
        international       :  {
            percentage           :  Number,
            developed            :  {
                percentage            :  Number,
                securities            :  [ { 
                    percentage             :  Number,
                    absolutePercentage     :  Number,
                    info                   :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'security' }
                } ]
            },
            emergent        :  {
                percentage            :  Number,
                securities            :  [ { 
                    percentage             :  Number,
                    absolutePercentage     :  Number,
                    info                   :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'security' }
                } ]
            }
        }
    },
    stocks          :  {
        percentage          :  Number,
        USA                 :  {
            percentage           :  Number,
            largeCaps            :  {
                percentage            :  Number,
                securities            :  [ { 
                    percentage             :  Number,
                    absolutePercentage     :  Number,
                    info                   :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'security' }
                } ]
            },
            mediumCaps           :  {
                percentage            :  Number,
                securities            :  [ { 
                    percentage             :  Number,
                    absolutePercentage     :  Number,
                    info                   :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'security' }
                } ]
            },
            smallCaps            :  {
                percentage            :  Number,
                securities            :  [ { 
                    percentage             :  Number,
                    absolutePercentage     :  Number,
                    info                   :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'security' }
                } ]
            }
        },
        international       :  {
            percentage           :  Number,
            developed            :  {
                percentage            :  Number,
                securities            :  [ {
                    percentage             :  Number,
                    absolutePercentage     :  Number,
                    info                   :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'security' }
                } ]
            },
            emergent        :  {
                percentage            :  Number,
                securities            :  [ { 
                    percentage             :  Number,
                    absolutePercentage     :  Number,
                    info                   :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'security' }
                } ]
            }
        }
    },
    goal               :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'goal' },
    createdAt          :  { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updatedAt          :  { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

As you can see, this is a representation of portfolio and you can look at the percentages for each bucket in two different ways: relative or absolute.

For example, we can take the percentage only in relation to the bonds (relative), or in relation the the whole portfolio (absolute).

```
this.bonds.USA.percentage = 50% (relative)
this.bonds.USA.absolutePercentage = 25%
```

My solution to do this in Mongoose was to use Virtuals, that when you change one of the percentages you also "change" the other, and you don't have to store both values (that represent the same thing) in the database.

However, the securities, such as `this.bonds.USA.treasury.securities`, are inside an array and I can't create a Virtual for it. I would need to create a separate schema to use virtuals and this would result in a 3 level deep population in my routes, which is very nasty...

So, my question is: Is there another solution (in addition to create a separate schema and use Virtuals) to make the `relativePercentage` be related to the `absolutePercentage` in a way that when I change one of them, it automatically updates the other one?